# Organizing <pre> Tag Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pre

I am trying to get the pre tag to break on the line breaks like how I have it displayed. Instead its putting the vv section on the first, not breaking in the middle of the comments comment section, etc. Is there some CSS for this that might be helpful?

```css
.testingZone {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.testingZone a {
  color: blue;
}
.testingZone a:hover {
  color: gold;
}
.testingZone pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="testingZone">
  <pre>
          &lt;!-- Note: comment comment comment.
          Comment Comment/Comment, more comments "comment"--&gt;
          &lt;vv:aaa vv:bbb="sss" vv:ccc="SectionA;SectionB;SectionC=SectionD;SectionE=SectionF.SectionG.SectionH;,SectionI=SectionJ;SectionK=SectionL;SectionM=SectionN;SectionO=SectionP.SectionQ.SectionR;SectionS=/;"/&gt;
          &lt;vv:aaa vv:bbb="iii" vv:ccc="\SectionT\SectionU\_SectionV,\SectionW\SectionX,\SectionY\_SectionZ"/&gt;
        </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing `white-space: normal` from the CSS, and letting `pre` behave like it normally does, solves the problem.

Comment: I tried that but then there is a extra line between the spot where I used the BR. It's like there is two <br>'s. You can test it in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ThePieMonster/67omozn9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `white-space: normal;`, use `white-space: pre-line;`. This allows runs of white-space to be combined within a line, but doesn't allow lines to be merged. This will merge all the leading spaces on each line into a single space.

```css
.testingZone {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.testingZone pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="testingZone">
  <pre>
          &lt;!-- Note: comment comment comment.
          Comment Comment/Comment, more comments "comment"--&gt;
          &lt;vv:aaa vv:bbb="sss" vv:ccc="SectionA;SectionB;SectionC=SectionD;SectionE=SectionF.SectionG.SectionH;,SectionI=SectionJ;SectionK=SectionL;SectionM=SectionN;SectionO=SectionP.SectionQ.SectionR;SectionS=/;"/&gt;
          &lt;vv:aaa vv:bbb="iii" vv:ccc="\SectionT\SectionU\_SectionV,\SectionW\SectionX,\SectionY\_SectionZ"/&gt;
    </pre>
</div>
```

There's no way to totally ignore all the white-space at the beginning of each line. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) for descriptions of all the `white-space` styles.

Comment: Yes but then I have white space to the left of each line.

Comment: &lt;pre&gt; tags render it's content exactly as written. To remove the left white space, remove the white space inside the pre-tag.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJQRbW

Comment: I've changed it to `white-space: pre-line;`. This will combine all the spaces at the beginning of the line into a single space. AFAIK, there's no way to ignore them completely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the white-space rule on the .testingZone pre tag or set it to the default for <pre> tags, which is 'pre'.

So basically: Change

```
.testingZone pre {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

to

```
.testingZone pre {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

or to

```
.testingZone pre {
    font-family: monospace;
    white-space: pre;
}
```